# bundle exec rake jobs:work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am newbie to Ruby on Rails development

Can someone please give explain to me what this command line do `bundle exec rake jobs:work`

I don't understand what is worker and what the command line can do.

Can someone gives me some examples.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

In ruby due to GIL(global interpreter lock), you can run only one ruby thread (multithreading is supported, but it works only if you do IO) at a time. To work around this issue and make things asynchronous, people use [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq), [delayedjob](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job), [etc](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/background_jobs).

Worker in this terminology, is a separate background ruby process that processes jobs a.k.a task you put in it. And if you use `DelayedJob` the `bundle exec rake jobs:work` will start this processes *(other gems for background jobs use other commands)*